# My content has a bad position and go behind my header

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I am here because I tried many option to resolve my problem but it doesn't appeart that it works.
I am explaining:
In some pages of my websites, I have a strange positioning of my content as you could see here:
[my screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aazZ5.png)

The problem is that my content has a bad position, i can't see correctly and it goes behind my header. In the other page it's perfect but here is not.

By advance, thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Up please I need help

Comment: Have you tried checkin if the pages where this doesn't happen have the same page template of the ones you have this issue with?

Comment: Hello, yes it's the same template i have this problem only in this page on the others everything is okay

Comment: Ok, then I'd recommend you to inspect the header that has the problem and see if there are any css rules that cause that, I can try that myself if you provide me with a link.